# Should shell32.dll be in executable search path for winword.exe with WinDBG?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

[image]I'm threat hunting and I'm curious if there should be a shell32.dll in the executable search path in windbg for winword.exe.

Comment: What / where are you disassembling / data ? The disassembly looks invalid ins outs etc are dos era instructions and wouldnt be valid in a 64 bit user mode app

Comment: What does it mean and how did it happen?

Comment: @InvulnerableImmortal you are in the DOS stub. If you convert the bytes to ascii it reads 'This program cannot be run in DOS mo'...

Comment: Unfortunately you don't state it in your question, but looking at the output I'll go by the assumption you're using Windows 11. No: `shell32.dll` is a so-called _known DLL_. Unless loaded with a fully qualified path, the official `shell32.dll` will be mapped to the process by the loader essentially. There is a "preloaded" (by the session manager) global section object available for each of the known DLLs - two sets exist on systems with WOW64 - in `\KnownDlls` and `\KnownDlls32` respectively. You could see them in WinObj or `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDLLs`.

Answer (score 1):

As i commented the area you are disassembling does not look like a valid code

As to how did it happen you should know better you have provided the address for disassembling 0x7ffc6b54000 and that address is probably located in advapi32.dll's resource section in the virtual address space of the process

Comment: I just thought that it was something different. I actually don't know anything, I'm new to this.